# How to get "load average" by command/procedure in Windows

Tags: windows, load, cpu, cpu-usage

I can use command like 'top' or 'uptime' to check "load average" in Linux. 
Can I check "load average" in Windows ? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When I search I found it is not possible with windows. You have to calculate it by getting other stats